# Accessing account information in Django Allauth confirmation email

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am using a custom e-mail message by overriding the default confirmation email of Django Allauth `email_confirmation_message.txt`

I have a custom signup form that also collects first and last name so I would like to access the first name that they have given during signup, in my e-mail confirmation. So you can address someone with his first name.

This is what the default template looks like:

```
{% load account %}
{% user_display user as user_display %}
{% load i18n %}
{% autoescape off %}

Dear {{ first name given at registration here }}

...

 {{ activate_url }}

...

{% endautoescape %}
```

It uses `{% user_display user as user_display %}` to display the username. So there must be a way to access the first name as well?

How can I access the first name in this e-mail? Or is this not possible without completely writing a custom confirmation e-mail?